# Download a zip archive and extract one file from it

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I wrote a function that downloads a file `https://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/tiedostot/junar.zip` if it not already downloaded, unzips it and returns the content of `junar1.in` found in this zip. I have PEP8 complaints about the length of lines that I would like to fix. Is there a way to make the code more readable?

My code :

```
import os.path
import urllib.request
import shutil
import zipfile


def download_and_return_content():
    if not os.path.isfile('/tmp/junar.zip'):
        url = 'https://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/tiedostot/junar.zip'
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open('junar.zip', 'wb') as out:
            data = response.read() # a `bytes` object
            out.write(data)
        shutil.move('junar.zip','/tmp')
    with zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/junar.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall('/tmp/')
    with open('/tmp/junar1.in') as f:
        return f.read()
```

Comment: Hey juniorprogrammer, I edited your question to make it more to the "CodeReview Format"' please check it out. Feel free to rollback the edit if you don't like it, but I think your question will receive more attention this way :)

Comment: You seem to have omitted the `import` statements when pasting here - could you please reinstate them?  Thanks.

Comment: True. I edited my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start refactoring/optimizations:

- `urllib` should be replaced with [`requests`](https://realpython.com/python-requests/) library which is the de facto standard for making HTTP requests in Python and has reach and flexible interface.
- instead of moving from intermediate location (`shutil.move('junar.zip','/tmp')`) we can just save the downloaded zip file to a destination path `with open('/tmp/junar.zip', 'wb') as out`
- decompose the initial function into 2 separate routines: one for downloading zipfile from specified location/url and the other - for reading a specified (passed as an argument) zipfile's *member/inner file*
- reading from `zipfile.ZipFile.open` directly to avoid intermediate extraction. Otherwise zipfile contents should be extracted at once, then - just reading a regular files being extracted (with adjusting the "reading" function)

---

From theory to practice:

```
import os.path
import requests
import zipfile
import warnings


def download_zipfile(url):
    if not os.path.isfile('/tmp/junar.zip'):
        with open('/tmp/junar.zip', 'wb') as out:
            out.write(requests.get(url).content)


def read_zipfile_item(filename):
    with zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/junar.zip') as zip_file:
        with zip_file.open(filename) as f:
            return f.read().decode('utf8')

# Testing
url = 'https://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/tiedostot/junar.zip'
download_zipfile(url=url)
print(read_zipfile_item('junar1.in'))
```

The actual output (until the input url is accessible):

```
10
6
1
4
10
7
2
3
9
5
8
```

Comment: That is fine with me - I have deleted mine. Please feel free to add your point 3 back. If you do please add the rational that you stated in the comments, thank you.

Comment: @Peilonrayz, mine were deleted. As for turning back the 3rd thesis, I'm not sure whether it's worthwhile as it evoked  a negative "reaction". I didn't quite follow why just *optionally logging failed downloading attempts (logger.warning(...))* can cause such a critics. In my understanding, if it happened once, then, hypothetically that fragment could be negatively perceived by someone else again. So maybe we may leave it uncovered/hidden.

Comment: Where to log information can be subjective, but ultimately alerting the user that a different behavior will occur due to X condition is never a bad thing. I think the sticking point may have been using `warning` which implies that something needs attention when maybe `info` might be a bit more appropriate. However, I stand by the premise that having alerting is better than none :)

Answer (score 2):

## PEP-8 Line Length

For particularly lengthy lines, you can always use parentheses to wrap them instead of the usual `\` sign:

```py
x = (1 + 2 + 3 +
     4 + 5 + 6)
```

## Function Refactor

I would skip the step in your `if` statement where you use `shutil.move`, just save the file in `/tmp` directly:

```py
def download_and_return_content():
    if not os.path.isfile('/tmp/junar.zip'):
        url = 'https://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/tiedostot/junar.zip'
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open('/tmp/junar.zip', 'wb') as out:
            data = response.read() # a `bytes` object
            out.write(data)
```

Furthermore, if you are just looking to extract a single file, you can open one of the archives directly using [`ZipFile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open)

```py
    with ZipFile('/tmp/junar.zip') as myzip:
        with myzip.open('junar1.in') as f:
            return f.read()
```

`ZipFile` can also take a file-like object, so you can use a `BytesIO` object to hold your zip-file bytes, since `/tmp` implies you might not need to hold onto this data:

```py
from io import BytesIO

def download_and_return_content():
    # your temporary file-handle
    tmp_file = BytesIO()

    url = 'https://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/tiedostot/junar.zip'
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        tmp_file.write(response.read())

    tmp_file.seek(0)

    with ZipFile(tmp_file) as myzip:
        with myzip.open('junar1.in') as fh:
            return fh.read()
```

Lastly, the `if` check implies that maybe you want to cache the data somehow. You could *in theory* use `BytesIO` as a mutable default. You can use `BytesIO.tell()` as your check if it has content:

```py
def get_content(tmp=BytesIO()):
    # buffer is at position 0, it has not been read or written to
    # therefore it is probably empty
    if not tmp.tell():
        tmp.truncate() # just in case
        url = 'https://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/tiedostot/junar.zip'
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
            tmp.write(response.read())

    # set buffer to position 0 to read content
    tmp.seek(0)

    with ZipFile(tmp) as myzip:
        # this will move the buffer to a non-zero position
        # so, now tmp.tell() will be non-zero and will pass the
        # if check on the next function call
        with myzip.open('junar1.in') as fh:
            return fh.read()
```

As a caveat, there are caching libraries in python that can accomplish this as well, I'm just not familiar enough with them to suggest any in a meaningful way.

Before everybody grabs their torches and pitchforks, the non-mutable-default way (usually mutable defaults are seen as bad design) could look something like this:

```py
# refactor into two functions, one that does the actual urllib call
# for you to retrieve your data
def get_data(tmp=None):
    tmp = tmp or BytesIO()

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        tmp.write(response.read())

    return tmp

# and one to actually extract the file
def extract_file(tmp=None):
    tmp = tmp or get_data()

    tmp.seek(0)

    with ZipFile(tmp) as myzip:
        with myzip.open('junar1.in') as fh:
            return fh.read()


# now you can hold that BytesIO object
tmp_file = get_data()

content = extract_file(tmp_file)
# returns b'10\r\n6\r\n1\r\n4\r\n10\r\n7\r\n2\r\n3\r\n9\r\n5\r\n8\r\n'

# and if you want to write that temp file somewhere
with open('/tmp/somefile.zip', 'wb') as fh:
    tmp_file.seek(0)
    fh.write(tmp_file.read())
```

Of course this all depends on what you need that zipfile for, but this cuts down on the amount of reads and writes you are doing under the hood.